# How to prove the equivalence of the optimization methods for Support Vector Machine

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming

I am studying Support Vector Machines from [ISLR](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/ISLR%20First%20Printing.pdf) and I am stuck on the following optimization problem (page 346) -

\begin{align}
\underset{w}{\text{maximize }} & \frac{M}{\|w\|} \\[6pt]
\text{subject to }
&y^{(i)}(w^Tx^{(i)} +b) \geq M(1 - \epsilon_i), \; i = 1, \ldots, m.\\[6pt]
&\epsilon_i \geq 0, \; i = 1, \ldots, m.\\[6pt]
&\sum_{1}^m \epsilon_i\ \leq C
\end{align}

Here $M$ is the functional margin.

How is this optimization problem equivalent to the more conventional optimization problem ([ESL](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/printings/ESLII_print10.pdf) page 439) - 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{w}{\text{minimize}}
& & \|w\|^2 + C \sum_{1}^{m} \epsilon_i\\
& \text{subject to}
& & y^{(i)}(w^Tx^{(i)} +b) \geq 1 - \epsilon_i, \; i = 1, \ldots, m.
& & \epsilon_i \geq 0, \; i = 1, \ldots, m.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

I understand how maximization became minimization and how M became 1. However, I am unable to understand how did $C$ went up into the objective function (along with the $\epsilon_i$)

I apologize if this is the wrong place to post this question. Kindly migrate it to a more suitable forum, if needed.